# How can I replace a word in SQL but only if it is the last word in the string for a scalar-valued function?

Tags: sql, database, function, replace, find

I am trying to use a function to clean address data and want to replace the word "Street" with "St" but only in the cases where "Street" is the last word in the string.  See the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfj8N.png)

I tried using a WHERE clause like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDoHI.png)

but i get a syntax error likely b/c this is not an actual column but part of the function i built.

Any help appreciated. thanks

I tried using a WHERE clause like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDoHI.png)

but i get a syntax error likely b/c this is not an actual column but part of the function i built.

Any help appreciated. thanks

Comment: also, DONT put images, just put code as text..

Comment: you dont need a where condition if you are setting variable

Comment: UPDATE yourtable SET column = REPLACE(column, 'Street', 'St') WHERE column LIKE '%Street' -- or set a value for variable - no where condition

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.